# How to read a file and print it, skipping certain lines in python

Tags: python, file, loops

I would like to read a file line by line but ignore any that contain a colon (:).

I'm currently opening one file, reading it, and trying to print it before eventually put it into a new file.

```
def shoppinglist():
    infile = open('filename.txt')
    contents = infile.readline()
    output = open('outputfilename.txt', 'w')
    while ":" not in contents:
        contents = infile.readline()
    else:
        contentstr = contents.split()
        print(contentstr)
    output.write(contents)
    infile.close()
    output.close()
```

As it is, one line is repeated over and over and over.

Comment: I don't see how you get more than a single line of output from this.  Your function reads the first and checks it for a colon.  It never reads a second line, and exits.

Comment: Yeah, it there a way to make it keep find that line, print it, then repeat until the end of the file?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python read and write files", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def shoppinglist():
    contents = ""
    with open('filename.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
            if ":" not in line:
                contents += line

    with open('outputfilename.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(contents)
```